# Java foreach using reference to replace items won't work

Tags: java, foreach

In an exercice we must replace an object by another within a loop. My solution is to use the "ListIterator". But a colleague try to use the foreach syntax and play the reference but this solution won't work.

```
// This doesn't work
for ( Growable growable : growables ) {
  growable = growable.grow(); // Return another object (seed -> sprout, ..)
}

// But that well
for (final ListIterator<Growable> it = growables.listIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  it.set(it.next().grow());
}
```

From the documentation[1], I can read that the foreach is not suitable for replacement because we don't have a reference to the iterator.

> The program needs access to the iterator in order to remove the current element. The for-each loop hides the iterator, so you cannot call remove. Therefore, the for-each loop is not usable for filtering. Similarly it is not usable for loops where you need to replace elements in a list or array as you traverse it.

But we have a reference to the iterated object. Am I wrong ? 
Can someone explain me why the "foreach" solution isn't working ?

Thanks

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first snippet, you take an element from `growables` and assign it to `growable`. This means that the variable `growable` *references* that element.

If you reassign `growable`, it starts referencing another object. But that doesn't change the object from `growables`.

---

To understand what's going on, you could compare this with an array. Using foreach syntax:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
for (int x : array) {
    x = 0;
}
System.out.println(array[0]);
```

This will print `1`. The reason is that this snippet is equivalent to

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int x = array[i];
    x = 0;
}
System.out.println(array[0]);
```

Now it's more obvious that assignment to `x` does not modify `array`.

Answer (score 0):

In the foreach case, growable is just assigned a value, which will be forgotten in the next step as a new iteration will happen and growable's value will be overwritten with the next element in growables